# Mean and Variance of a Differenced Time Series

Tags: time-series, modeling, trend, differencing

Suppose I am differencing a time series. I decide to try out differencing for $d=1, 2$, and $3$ where $d$ is the order of the differencing (by convention of the R function `diff()`). If $d=2$ illustrates a smaller mean and variance than the other differenced time series, does that imply that $d=2$ does the best job at removing trends?

Comment: Can you explain what $d$ is?

Comment: $d$ is the order of the differencing @jcken